# Cache-Control not working in Angular cli

Tags: angular, .htaccess, http-headers, angular-cli, cache-control

I want to use Cache-Control in my Angular-cli application so that when i will reload the browser,all files should not come from cache. I used

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=60"/>
```

in index.html.But not worked. After that i used .htaccess file.Below is the content of my .htaccess file.

```
# One minute for html,css and js
<filesMatch ".(html|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60"
</filesMatch>
```

Created the .htaccess file in src folder and add it to angular-cli.json

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "assets/images",
    ".htaccess"
  ],
```

But still browser is taking all files from cache.
can any one help me to solve the issue?